# Pagebreak for contents in pdf and print

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf

I have a html which will be generated to pdf. I have few tables in that. How can i break the content to next page if the content is big ?

I have tried using the `page-break-after:always` but had no effect.

Comment: You will have to check the documentation of the library that you are using to generate pdf.

Comment: are you getting the problem for all browsers or just any specific browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below rules can help you add page break for tables.

```
   table { page-break-inside:auto }
   tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
```

Or try adding a div as:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

with styles:

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help.